# Empty Operation name in Azure application insight (Performance menu)

Tags: azure, go, azure-application-insights, go-gin

With the following middleware, we get empty OPERATION NAME in Azure application insight **Performance** menu. What am I missing here?

Gin router setup:

```
if key, ok := os.LookupEnv("APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"); ok {
        insightsConfig := &middleware.InsightsConfig {
            InstrumentationKey: key,
            Role:    "myapp",
        }
        router.Use(middleware.InsightsWithConfig(insightsConfig))
        }
```

Middleware:

```
func InsightsWithConfig(config *InsightsConfig) gin.HandlerFunc {
        client := createTelemetryClient(config)
        return func(c *gin.Context) {
            url := c.Request.RequestURI
            start := time.Now()
            c.Next()
            end := time.Now()
            duration := end.Sub(start)
            clientIP := c.ClientIP()
            method := c.Request.Method
            statusCode := c.Writer.Status()
            userAgent := c.Request.UserAgent()
            bodySize := c.Writer.Size()
            telemetry := appinsights.NewRequestTelemetry(method, url, duration, strconv.Itoa(statusCode))
            telemetry.Timestamp = end
            telemetry.MarkTime(start, end)
            telemetry.Source = clientIP
            telemetry.Success = statusCode >= 200 && statusCode < 400
            telemetry.Properties["user-agent"] = userAgent
            telemetry.Measurements["body-size"] = float64(bodySize)
            client.Track(telemetry)
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have missed to mention instrumentation key in your code that could be the reason for the empty operation name in Azure application Insight.

[image]

As per the below code include the instrumentation key in your code.

```
func createTelemetryClient(config *InsightsConfig) appinsights.TelemetryClient {  
client := appinsights.NewTelemetryClient(config.InstrumentationKey)
```

Check this [Work around](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Go/issues/25#issuecomment-471945346) with the related discussions.

Comment: I am sorry for skipping the caller code. Application insight key is provided by the caller. Telemetry is successfully sent to Application insight, it's only the OPERATION NAME is missing in the **Performance** Dashboard in Azure Application Insight portal (Something looks like POST /myapp/public/login)

```if key, ok := os.LookupEnv("APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"); ok {
  insightsConfig := &middleware.InsightsConfig {
   InstrumentationKey: key,
        Role:    "myapp",
  }
  router.Use(middleware.InsightsWithConfig(insightsConfig))
 }```